# npm run build error with Create React App and TailwindCSS

Tags: reactjs, webpack, tailwind-css

When I run `npm run build` I get this error, why? I don't know if it has to do with TailwindCSS...

> Creating an optimized production build...
> Failed to compile.

> static/css/main.a923260e.css from Css Minimizer plugin
> /home/user/Documentos/coding/projects/todofeito app/client/static/css/main.a923260e.css:1882:43: Unknown word [webpack://./src/index.css:3,0][static/css/main.a923260e.css:1882,43]

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "todofeito-app-new",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-hook/resize-observer": "^1.2.6",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^4.3.9",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.20",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "date-fns": "^2.29.3",
    "framer-motion": "^7.3.6",
    "i18next": "^22.0.4",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^7.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "nanoid": "^4.0.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.1",
    "react-device-detect": "^2.2.2",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-expanding-textarea": "^2.3.6",
    "react-i18next": "^12.0.0",
    "react-list": "^0.8.17",
    "react-portal": "^4.2.2",
    "react-resizable": "^3.0.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-select": "^5.6.0",
    "tailwindcss-scoped-groups": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.8.3",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "zustand": "^4.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "test2": "jest"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.18.6",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.186",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.4",
    "@types/react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.2",
    "@types/react-list": "^0.8.7",
    "@types/react-portal": "^4.0.4",
    "@types/react-resizable": "^3.0.3",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^27.1.3",
    "jest": "^27.5.1",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.2.2",
    "postcss": "^8.4.19",
    "postcss-normalize": "^10.0.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.8"
  }
}
```

Comment: can you show your folder structure in project? it can error from structure when build

Answer (score 0):

yeah, I got the same error when I try to build, but I was able to run the project by yarn start without any style breaking or issues.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I faced the same error.
Problem was TailwindCSS grammar issue.
npx tailwindcss -i ./src/App.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch
Once using this command, you can see dist/output.css file.
The file is one that converted tailwind css to css.
then you can see css grammar issue.
For example,

```
table {
  text-indent: 0;
  /* 1 */
  border-color: inherit;
  /* 2 */
  border-collapse: collapse;;
  /* 3 */
}
```

once you fix the issue, npm run build will work